# determine image size of jpeg and png image before saving it

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm taking an image from the clipboard and trying to determine how much the image going to take space on a hard drive before actually saving it. I couldn't find the right code to do so.

I'm using this code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab
from io import BytesIO

def jpeg_or_png(img):
    img_file = BytesIO()
    img.save(img_file, 'png')
    img_file_size_png = img_file.tell()
    img_file = BytesIO()
    img.save(img_file, 'jpeg')
    img_file_size_jpeg = img_file.tell()

    if img_file_size_jpeg < img_file_size_png:
        return 'jpeg'
    else:
        return 'png'


img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
if img:
    print(jpeg_or_png(img))
```

It always returns `jpeg`. Even if it's a blank white part image, for which `png` is more efficient.

If I save both versions, and of course `.png` is smaller in size, but the function still returns `.jpeg`.

Ideally, I want to determine which extension is going to take less space without saving it. I know I can save both, then find out the biggest file and remove it. But it's bad practice and form to do that because it will take up space to do that.

Comment: Try to use separate variables for each format. You use `img_file` twice, try to use `png_file` and `jpeg_file`. It could be a reason.

Comment: I fixed it, and it wasn't the problem. This code works for others, but strangely enough, not for me.

Answer (score 1):

You code works for me.  To help diagnose, you can modify your function to return the size of the image as a dictionary.

```
def jpeg_or_png(img):
    j = BytesIO()
    img.save(j, 'jpeg')
    p = BytesIO()
    img.save(p, 'png')
    return {'jpg': j.tell(), 'png':p.tell()}
```

Here are two tests with different screen captures:

```
jpeg_or_png(ImageGrab.grabclipboard())
# returns:
{'jpg': 21753, 'png': 232163}
```

for this image:

[image]

```
jpeg_or_png(ImageGrab.grabclipboard())
# returns:
{'jpg': 7479, 'png': 3602}
```

for this image:

[image]

Comment: And this exact code for the bottom image returns
{'jpg': 7261, 'png': 27323}
What the heck?

Comment: For a top image the result is this
{'jpg': 23206, 'png': 180989}

Comment: Just to note, I'm using python 3.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.14.2

Comment: whoa...not sure why it would be so different.  i am on Win10

Comment: Do you have any idea why it may happen?